# Unable to Scan MultiBarcodes at same time using zxing in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am using Zxing Library to scan bar codes,
I am successfully scan single bar code but not able to scan multi bar code in a single image.

Comment: You have to specify the scanning dimensions. Then only, it will scan the barcode which you placing into that dimensions.

Comment: hi hari i am not getting the point scanning dimension, currently i am using full screen to scan